# Facing authentication error on postgres 9.2 -> dblink functions

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgres 9.2 and when executing function dblink facing a fatal error while trying to execute dblink_connect as follows:

> SELECT * FROM dblink_connect('host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=postgres
>   password=test')
>
> ERROR:  could not establish connection DETAIL:  FATAL:  password
>   authentication failed for user "NETWORK SERVICE"

What this error is related to? Do I need to modify `pg_hba.conf` file by any
chance?

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what operating system you're using, and what type of authentication you've configured?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `user` parameter in the connect string, for example:

```
SELECT dblink_connect('host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=test')
```

otherwise it's taken from the user account's name and obviously it's not suitable in your case.